# Django object filter - price behaving strangely, eg 170 treated as 17 etc

Tags: django, string, object, filter, decimal

I have a simple object filter that uses `price__lt` and `price__gt`. This works on a property on my product model called price, which is a `CharField` [string] (decimal saw the same errors, and caused trouble with aggregation so reverted to string).

It seems that when passing in these values to the filter, they are treated in a strange way, eg 10 is treated as 100. for example:

`/products/price/10-200/`  returns products priced 100-200. the filters are being passed in as filterargs:   `FILTER ARGS: {'price__lt': '200', 'price__gt': '10'}` . This also breaks in the sense that price/0-170   will NOT return products priced at 18.50; it is treating the 170 as 'less than 18' for some reason.

any idea what would cause this, and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Can you copy and paste the corresponding urlpattern (from urls.py)?

Comment: Quick thinking suggests that as you swapped to a charfield any comparisons done will be based on chars where I guess 17(0) comes before 18? I would look into converting the values to decimal before running the comparison.

Comment: I believe that the url pattern is irrelevant as the filterargs output shown above {'price_lt': '200', 'price_gt': '10'} is from a print in the views.py just before it is passed in to Products.objects.filter(filterargs)

Comment: I think this helps show the problem. It is a print for the product price for all items sorted by price low to high, and prints the type:

->price: 253.95 <type 'unicode'>
->price: 253.95 <type 'unicode'>
->price: 26.45 <type 'unicode'>
->price: 26.45 <type 'unicode'>

As you can see the price is unicode (should be decimal) and a a result it order 26.45 behind 253.95. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem, as Jeff suggests, is that price is a `CharField` and thus is being compared using character-by-character string comparison logic, i.e. any string of any length starting with `1` will be less than any string of any length starting with `2`, etc.

I'm curious what problems you were having with having price be an `IntegerField`, as that would seem to be the straightforward solution, but if you need to keep price as a `CharField`, here's a (hacky) way to make the query work:

```
lt = 200
gt = 10
qs = Product.objects.extra(select={'int_price': 'cast(price as int)'},
                           where=['int_price < %s', 'int_price > %s'],
                           params=[lt, gt])
qs.all()  # the result
```

This uses the `extra` method of Django's QuerySet class, which you can read about in the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra). In a nutshell, it computes an integer version of the string price using SQL's `cast` expression and then filters with integers based on that.

Comment: ah thanks Ghopper. I found the problem: basically I built the initial model using charfield, then when i changed to decimalfield i didn't reset the app and rebuild db, so it was, as suggested above, shoving decimals into a string field. Thanks and sorry about this!