# Django queries and data type convert

Tags: python, django, django-models

If I have such a model:

```
class A(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
```

The `value` attribute of `A` is actually a number, for instances, `'50'`

Now I want such `A instances` whose value, as a number, is between `10` and `100`. How do I make the query?

Normally, `'50' > '100'`

Ps. This problem is extracted from a complex circumstance and I don't want to use `IntegerField` or `DecimalField`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Django object filter - price behaving strangely, eg 170 treated as 17 etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843342/django-object-filter-price-behaving-strangely-eg-170-treated-as-17-etc)

You can use answer from this question.

But it's really some hacky, maybe you should write custom lookups.